# jQuery button click change image

Tags: jquery

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    //debugger;
    if ($("img[id=image][src:contains(Grass)]"))
        $("img").attr({ src: "/Content/images/Spring.jpg", alt: "Spring" });
    else
        $("img").attr({ src: "/Content/images/Grass.jpg", alt: "Grass" });
});

<a href="/Content/images/Grass.jpg"><img src="/Content/images/Grass.jpg" alt="image"    id="image"/></a>
<input type="button" id="button" name="button"/>
```

I have simple form with image and button, i want on each button click image getting changed. The logic is very simple. By default `image src = /Content/images/Grass.jpg` When i click button first time image getting changed, but when i am click second time it is does not changed back. I check in debugger and find out that condition `$("img[id=image][src:contains(Grass)]")` always `true`. But after first button click shouldn't it became false then?

if i declare

```
    var img1 = $("img#image[src:contains(Grass)]");
    var img2 = $("img#image[src:contains(Grass2)]");
    var img3 = $("img#image[src:contains(blabla)]");
```

each img1.length = 1 img2.length = 1 img3.length = 1 
Why?

but

```
var img1 = $("img#image[src*='Grass']");
var img2 = $("img#image[src*='Grass2']");
var img3 = $("img#image[src*='blabla']");
```

each img1.length = 1 img2.length = 0 img3.length = 0 it is what was expected.

Does it means that `src:contains(text)` and `src*=text` is so different?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#button").click(function () {
  var alt = ($('img#image[alt="Grass"]').length) ? 'Spring' : 'Grass';
  $('img#image').attr({ src: "/Content/images/"+alt+".jpg", alt:alt });
});

<a href="/Content/images/Grass.jpg">
  <img src="/Content/images/Grass.jpg" alt="Grass" id="image"/>
</a>
<input type="button" id="button" name="button"/>
```

Comment: Should be "img#image", not image#img, why in that case is better to check alt?

Comment: but if i am wouldn't set alt. If alt is constant? I need to check src anyway.

Comment: there is no need to add the `img` before the `#image` selector.  `#image` is highly optimized because its an id, and you should never duplicate id's so there will never be a `#image` that isn't a `img`

Answer (score 2):

The line `if ($("img[id=image][src:contains(Grass)]"))` will always be true. The $() function returns a jQuery object, and an object always evaluate to **true**. You need to check that the length of the result is not 0.

`if ($("img[id=image][src:contains(Grass)]").length > 0)`

Comment: Incidentally, this code isn't a very good way to do things, and I would advise against using it in a production site. But if you're just experimenting with how jQuery works, then this answer will give you what you need.

Comment: Not working, i watch in debug, in both cases($("img[id=image][src:contains(Grass)]").length and $("img[id=image][src:contains(Spring)]").length ) at the same time i am getting length equal to 1

Comment: @Jason LeBrun I am just experimenting, but what is the better way of doing this?

Comment: It depends on your ultimate goal, but when I want to toggle between two images like this, I generally include them both in the source, with a unique id attribute set. Set `visibility: none` CSS property on the one I don't want shown. Then, to toggle between them, just change the `visibility` property for each one when the button is pressed. It's much more efficient to look something up by DOM ID then by attribute values.

Comment: `[src:contains(Grass)]` is an invalid selector. `:contains` searches the content of the element not of attributes. http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var img = $("#image"),
    a = img.parent('a');
$("#button").click(function () {
    var str = (img.attr('src').search('Grass') != -1) ? "Spring" : "Grass",
        src =  "/Content/images/"+str+".jpg";
    img.attr({ src: src, alt: str });
    a.attr("href", src);
});
```

First we are caching the `#image` jQuery object, no need to select it each time the button is pressed.
Then we do a normal javascript search on the src string. If it has grass in it then we change it to spring.
Because we cached the `#image` jQuery object we don't have to reselect it to change the `src` and `alt` attributes.
Also if you are changing the img `src` I am guessing you probably want to update the link around it.

Comment: Does it meant that in that case selector $("img[id=image][src:contains(Grass)]") working not as expected?

Comment: @Reg yes :contains is a special selector that doesn't work on attributes. http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

One simple fix is to replace this:

```
$("img[id=image][src:contains(Grass)]")
```

...with this:

```
$("#image[src*=Grass]").length
```

[Related selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```
a^=b    a starts with b
a$=b    a ends with b
a!=b    a does not equal b
a*=b    a contains b
```

Comment: I am already fix this using [attribute*=value] instead of  [attribute:contains(value)] but still researching why they are returning different results. [attribute*=value] vs [attribute:contains(value)]

Answer (score 0):

```
          $("#button").click(function () {                
            var value = ($("img#image[src*='Grass']").length) ? 'Spring' : 'Grass';

            $("img").attr({ src: "/Content/images/" + value + ".jpg", alt: value });
          });
```