# How to change / alternate the background-position of an image on slideToggle()?

Tags: jquery, css

I found the code to open/close the div when I click a certain button.  Now I also want to make  not only the div open/close but the open/close button change from a down arrow to an up arrow.

This is what I have so far excuse me if my post is not correct as this is my first post.

The image is height = 60px and width = 30px.  The up arrow is on one half and down arrow is on the other half.

```
<style>
.content_toggle {
background: url(toggle-btn.png);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
bottom: 62px;
left: 850px;
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
}
</style>


<body>
<div class="content_toggle" style="display: block;"></div>

<script>
$("div.content_toggle").click(function () {
  $("div.content").slideToggle("slow");
});
</script>

<div class="content">content, content, content</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a helpful post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062731/jquery-toggle-to-change-image. And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840635/jquery-button-click-change-image?rq=1

Comment: Anthony - to keep everyone onside you want to tick your preferred answer and +1 (up arrow) liberally as soon as you have enough rating :)  The community can get a bit vicious to those who fail to do so.

Comment: No worries - just don't take it to heart if you get -1 once in a while :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a class for "arrow up" and another for "arrow down", then toggle between them as you toggle div visibility:

```
<style>
    .content_toggle {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        bottom: 62px;
        left: 850px;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
    }
    .arrow-up {
        background: url(toggle-btn.png);
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    .arrow-down {
        background: url(toggle-btn.png);
        background-position: 0 -30;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="content_toggle arrow-up" style="display: block;"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div.content_toggle").click(function() {
                var self = $(this); //cache jQuery object
                $("div.content").slideToggle("slow");
                if (self.hasClass("arrow-up")) {
                    self.removeClass("arrow-up").addClass("arrow-down");
                } else {
                    self.removeClass("arrow-down").addClass("arrow-up");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="content">content, content, content</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think the images are in the same image file not in 2 separate ones. Positioning the image in each class would probably be better in that case. Similar to what `galchen` mentioned.

Comment: Yes, it appears the images are in one file, although it is probably preferable and is certainly more standard to use two images :)

Comment: Then define the "arrow up" and "arrow down" classes appropriately (i.e., same image, but different positioning). The principle is the same.

Comment: @Nick not sure about that being standard. I'm more used to sprites and css positioning myself as standard. But that's another discussion :)

Comment: This demonstration wasn't working either.  Only galchen's is working for me.

Comment: @AnthonyRusso: I apologize. I misread which div needed the class toggled. Corrected code in update. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cga4L/ (although I had to change the `bottom` and `left` properties of the `.content_toggle` class in the fiddle to make sure no scrolling was needed).

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I bow to your expertise on what is standard and retract :)

Comment: @Nick Not sure if that was being sarcastic or not but so far the projects I was involved in the style-guys used sprites and exposed separate styles for sprite sheets and positioning. However if that is `the` standard I don't know at all. It just has been `a` standard for me personally. In the end, what ever works, works :)

Comment: @FrancoisWahl  No sarcasm at all. I'd just assumed from what I've rea that two images was standard, but I no longer work in the IT industry so I am quite ready to acknowledge others know better than I do :)

Comment: I thought this is what I wanted but when I click the button it doesn't do anything.  I thought I was doing something wrong so I copied your example exactly and it still didn't work even though it shows working in the fiddle.

Comment: @AnthonyRusso: Can you set up a fiddle with your code? It may help to figure out why yours is not working.

Comment: @pete I setup a fiddle, ran it with jquery 1.7.2, and it was working with the code I have so I guess my problem is I don't know how to properly input the jquery part into my html code.

Comment: @pete If you have any ideas what I might be doing wrong let me know on here or russoanthony@hotmail.com   THANK YOU

Comment: @AnthonyRusso: I realized my answer was not running on `$(document).ready()` which would definitely cause a problem. Updated answer. If this doesn't work, please post a link to your fiddle.

Comment: @pete  It works now.  Is there a way to get in contact with you directly if I have any questions or want to pay for you to make me something?

Comment: @AnthonyRusso: Glad it works now. If you need anything else, just post it here on SO. We're here to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the click handler will simply toggle a class named "active". You will need to write a css rule for `.content_toggle.active` that adjusts the image the way you want

```
$("div.content_toggle").click(function () {
      $("div.content").slideToggle("slow");       
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

since both arrows are in the same image, you will want to set the css background-position attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $("div.content_toggle").data('bgp',0).click(function () {
        $("div.content").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).data('bgp', 30 - $(this).data('bgp'));  // toggle the stored value
        $(this).css('background-position', '0 '+$(this).data('bgp')+'px'); // set the scss
    });
});
</script>
```

notice that i'm changing the background-position's y-axis by 30px

Comment: better to do it by referncing a CSS class that has the background-position adjusted  than doing it like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with `.toggle()`. You have more control and the code is more readable, i.e. to see what happens when.

And definitely use one or two classes for the open / closed state.

See example here: http://jsbin.com/anebug/edit#html,live

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  .content_toggle {
    background: url(toggle-btn.png);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    bottom: 62px;
    left: 850px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
  }
  .content { background-image:url(arrow.png); }
  .closed { background-position:0 -30px; } 
  .open { background-position:0 0; }
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div class="content_toggle" style="display: block;"></div>

<div class="content">content, content, content</div>


<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script>
  $("div.content_toggle").toggle(
      function() { $('.content').slideDown('slow',
                                  function(){$(this).removeClass('open')});}, 
      function() { $('.content').slideUp('slow',
                                  function(){$(this).addClass('closed')});
  });
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I agree to using a css class for background position but I tried this and it isn't working.  I could be missing something obvious.  galchen's demonstration is working for me.